# Why do people choose to follow a fruitarian diet?

Tags: fruitarianism

Many vegans switch to, or sometimes try to follow, a fruitarian diet. Which are their reasons? Is this for health or for some ethical reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to follow a Fruitarian diet? If not, what are the potential health issues?](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/109/is-it-safe-to-follow-a-fruitarian-diet-if-not-what-are-the-potential-health-is)

Comment: @DarrinThomas - Although this question and the duplicate target are about fruitarian diet, they ask about different things: _motivation_ vs. _health risks_.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruitarianism#Motivation) there are several reasons to consider a fruitarian diet:

- **Religion**

> Some fruitarians who espouse Judeo-Christian beliefs hold that
>   fruitarianism was the original diet of humankind in the form of Adam
>   and Eve, based on an uncommon interpretation of the Book of Genesis
>   1:29.[12] They believe that a return to an Eden-like paradise will
>   require simple living and a holistic approach to health and diet.

- **Non-violence principle** ([ahimsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahimsa_in_Jainism))

> Some fruitarians wish, like Jains, to avoid killing anything,
>   including plants, and refer to ahinsa fruitarianism.

- **Utopian / idealistic past fixation**

> Some fruitarians hope being to return to a past that predates an
>   agrarian society, to when humans were simply gatherers.

- **Detoxification** (detox)

> another common motivation is the desire to eliminate perceived
>   toxicity within the body

I think this is the primary cause for going fruitarian. Detox diets have raised concerns due to conjunction between popularity and risk. ([article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jhn.12286/abstract))

- **Challenging**

> The appeal of a fruitarian diet comes from the challenge that the
>   restrictive nature of this diet provides.